# The answer is not found same for the factorial (Parallel and Normal)

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Why is not the same answer for following?

Normal coding:

```
long sum = 0;

for (long i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    long result = 1;

    for (long j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        result = result*j;
    }
    sum = sum + result;
}
```

Parallel Coding:

```
long sum = 0;

Parallel.For(1, 10, delegate(int i)
    {
        long result = 1;

        Parallel.For(1, i, delegate(int j)
            {
                result = result*j;
            });

        sum = sum + result;
    });
```

Please show me the right way

```
for (long i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            sum = sum * i;
        }
```

and

```
Parallel.For(1, 5, delegate(int i)
    {
        sum = sum * i;
    });
```

Result of parallel = 24

Result of normal = 120

Comment: For any modestly sized value of i, computable with "int", the parallel overhead you invoke dominates the actual arithmetic, and you won't see any speed up.  If you insist on values of i that require a bignum package, you will likely see a speedup. (Your algorithm is pretty inefficient: for each j>k, you recompute k! repeatedly; you'd likely be better off caching k!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer in parallel version is arbitrary because `sum` and `result` are accessed and modified by different threads. So what you should do is separating between computing each step and summing up results. To be able to sum up results correctly, you need to obtain a lock so that threads modify `sum` exclusively. One way to fix could be:

```
long sum = 0;
object monitor = new object(); 
Parallel.For(1, 11, () => 0L, (i, state, local) => 
{ 
    long result = 1;

    for (long j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        result = result*j;
    } 
    return local + result;
}, local => { lock (monitor) sum += local; });
```

Note that you rarely need two nested `Parallel.For` loops, because they often lead to bad performance. So one `Parallel.For` loop at the outermost level and keeping inner `for` loops as they are is recommended. Also to obtain some speedup, you have to test with numbers much bigger than `10`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fast way of calculating factorials in Parallel.

```
    public static BigInteger Factorial(int n)
    {
        BigInteger temp = 1;

        Parallel.For(1, n + 1, (i) =>
        {
            temp *= i;
        });

        return temp;
    }
```